# locationManager authorization not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have an app that I am trying to get the authorization for LocationManager to show up. I had it working for Always but then tried When In Use.  Now I can't get either one to work

I have Placed
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription  string  enable to play
in my Info.plist

In my app delegate I have put

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];


    self.locationManager.delegate= self;


    return YES;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){

        NSLog(@"ok");

    }
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways){
        NSLog(@"Always");
    }
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse){
        NSLog(@"WhenInUse");
    }
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
        NSLog(@"restricted");
    }

    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        NSLog(@"denid");
        AlertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied"
                                                message:@"Please go to Settings/Privacy/Location Services to enable Always for this app to function properly."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [AlertView2 show];

    }
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
        NSLog(@"undetermined");

            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is what I had originally but I have tried every possible configuration, although obviously not.

Can someone help me get this thing working.  I would prefer WhenInUse but at this point I'll take anything

By the way I do get a call back of the NSLog undetermined in the last status but the included code is not called.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am officially an idiot.
I looked at my info.plist and there it was.  I had copied and pasted the Alway Description and changed it to WhenInUse and the when it didn't work I deleted the original and kept the copy and changed it back to Always.  However upon expanding the column to see the whole thing the was a -2 attached to the end so it wasn't formatted correctly so it didn't work.  Once I removed the -2 it works wonderful.  I have changed the original post to show how it works.  Thanks for all your help and I will make sure I address the concern you brought up.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

- I'd suggest setting the `delegate` before you request permission.
- What is `authorizationStatus` before you request permission? You should check it before you bother to request permission, because if they already refused permission, you want to tell them to fix settings. A request for permission will not result in anything (including a change in status) if permission was previously denied.

Comment: This is the first time this app is opened after install

Comment: You still need to fix these two issues. And, what was the "authorization status" in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Ok so I removed the requestAlwaysAuthorization from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and from the kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined.  In the log it shows the authorization as undetermined.  But no alert shows up asking to give permission and after the app is installed the app is not in the Settings/Privacy/LocationServices section.  I have a section that if the app was denied it shows an alert telling the user to go to settings and change the permission in the above code.  As I said this worked at one time but not now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This .....

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy  = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0f;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I am using this as a beacon does that matter.  and as I stated before I had this working with just location manager init, location manager delegate and location manager request  but I will try anything